# jQuery : Attaching mouseup event to all textnodes of a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, textnode

I want to attach a "mouseup" event on all nodes of a container, including text nodes using jQuery. How do I do that?

**Update:**

If I had some HTML fragment like this:

```
<p>Some text node <strong>strong text</strong> another text node.</p>
```

Currently, $("p *") will apply the event to the `<p>` and `<strong>` but not to the 2 textnodes within `<p>` separately. Modifying the source to add classes is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bobince is right that you cannot set event handlers on a Text node.  It sounds like you want something like

```
<p><span>Some text node</span> <strong>strong text</strong><span> another text node.</span></p>
```

and the events would get attached to the span tags.  However that wouldn't work if you can't change the source.

Comment: You could perhaps wrap the text nodes in tags from script, eg. something like `$.each(p.childNodes, function() { if (this.nodeType==3) $(this).wrap('<span></span>'); };`

Answer (score 2):

While Tatu's answer ought to work (except use .mouseup instead of .click), are you sure you actually need an event handler on every single node? If you bind using

`$('#container').mouseup(function(event){//code})`

the event bubbling model will call that same func anytime the mouseup event occurs on any element inside #container, and the DOM node that actually triggered the event will be contained in the event.target property. This is much more efficient in most cases.

Comment: Please see my the update to my question. When I do a alert(this) from the event handler, I want the node to be the textnode and not the parent <p> node.

Comment: I don't know if jQuery can select text nodes currently. There was a discussion on it here: http://www.mail-archive.com/jquery-en@googlegroups.com/msg14384.html

And an old prototype plugin for doing it here: http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/plugins/textNodes?rev=2052

Comment: @jefferyveon, you can get the actual node called using this technique. It's not jQuery, but here's a tutorial from sitepoint.com: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/#

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container *').mouseup(function() { ... });
```

That will bind the mouseup event handler to all nodes inside #container.

**EDIT**

Changed click -> mouseup to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set event handlers on a `Text` node. Text nodes do not implement the [EventTarget](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget) interface like `Element` nodes, the `Document` node and the `window` object do.

You should never need to, either. Set one `mouseup` handler on the parent element and you will get `mouseup` events for all its child content. This is because the `mouseup` event [‘bubbles’ up](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling) through its ancestors.

Comment: Ok, then how do I get a reference to the textnode that I click upon?

Comment: Sorry, you can't — not in any cross-browser way, anyhow; event originate only on EventTargets. Mozilla does give you `event.explicitOriginalTarget` that can point to a Text node but there's nothing on the other browsers. If you need to distinguish clicks in the text you'll need to wrap with elements (see rosscj's answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be to add a class to all your nodes.
The jquery selector will be as simple as :
$('.yourClassName').dostuff()